# Keep datepicker value and radio button selection after page refresh

Tags: datepicker, radio-button, refresh

I would like to keep my datepicker value and my radio button selection after my page refreshes. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using php + html?

Comment: I am using MVC so HTML and Jquery. @DavidAlves

Comment: Can you provide your code so far? HTML code of the form and the js code of where you keep those data?